# Responsive header slider with multiple elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a homepage slider on a website that obviously needs to be mobile responsive as well. I am using Bootstrap 3 as my framework. On desktop the slider needs to look as follows:

[image]

*Image* is the slider background image.
*Content block 1* is a semi-transparent content box with text over the image.
*Content block 2* is similar to content block 1 and is at the bottom of the image **but still over** the image.
*Main content block* is the rest of the website pages content.

On mobile, this should translate as below.

[image]

*Image* is the slider background image.
*Content block 1* is a semi-transparent content box with text **but below** the image.
*Content block 2* is similar to content block 1 and is below *Content block 1*.
*Main content block* is the rest of the website pages content.

On mobile, this seems to work as the content blocks are placed below/relative to the image. But on desktop, they are also placed below the image.
I make the margin-top: -50% on the desktop *Content Block 1* and it moves the content block up, but the image also scales (shrinks) with the same %.

My CSS.

```
.carousel-header-container { /* Content block 1 */
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0%;
    left: 10%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-content-row { /* Content block 2 */
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 8em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-header-container { /* Content block 1 */
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .carousel-content-row { /* Content block 2 */
        position: relative; 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 5em;
    }
}
```

And the HTML.

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="/images/myimage.jpg" style="width:100%; height: 100%">

    <div class="carousel-header-container">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet...<br>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-content-row">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet...<br>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    This is the rest of the page content.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
.item {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     position: relative;
}
```

to your CSS then set the divs you want on top of your image to `position: absolute` with `top` and `bottom` styles to your liking!

```css
.item {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-header-container { /* Content block 1 */
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-content-row { /* Content block 2 */
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50" style="width:100%; height: 100%">

    <div class="carousel-header-container">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet...<br>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-content-row">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet...<br>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    This is the rest of the page content.
</div>
```

NOTE: I left out your media query part, because it will effect the fiddle.

You should include it for your purposes tho.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-header-container { /* Content block 1 */
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .carousel-content-row { /* Content block 2 */
        position: relative; 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 5em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `position: absolute` to achieve what you want on desktop.

Change the style under `.carousel-header-container` to `position: absolute` and play around with the `top` property to adjust to what you are looking for.

Also, you don't need to repeat the properties that have the same values under the two `.carousel-header-container` sections. You will only need to redefine the values that are different under the section intended for mobile.